# Error inflating class <unknown> How to update resource.designer.cs correctly in xamarin on android project

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I want to use this [example](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/main/CustomRenderers/Map)

But In Android project in file `CustomRenderer` I miss in `resource.designer.cs` this elements:

```
XamarinMapInfoWindow
MapInfoWindow
InfoWindowTitle
InfoWindowSubtitle
```

When I added this elements in in class Layout in resource.deisgner.cs with this code:

```
        // aapt resource value: 0x7F0B0072
        public const int XamarinMapInfoWindow = 2131427442;

        // aapt resource value: 0x7F0B0032
        public const int MapInfoWindow = 2131427378;
```

And this two elements in class Id in resource.designer.cs:

```
// aapt resource value: 0x7F080006
        public const int InfoWindowSubtitle = 2131230726;

        // aapt resource value: 0x7F080007
        public const int InfoWindowTitle = 2131230727;
```

The pin's in the map are changed correctly but, when I click on some pin I receive this error message:

```
Binary XML file line #1 in pizhevsoft.weatherlocationinfo.maritsatundzhaforecast:layout/toolbar: Binary XML file line #1 in pizhevsoft.weatherlocationinfo.maritsatundzhaforecast:layout/toolbar: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

[image: Inflating class]

Comment: you don't edit the Resource.Designer.cs file directly.  When you modify the contents of your Resources folder the IDE will do that for you.

Comment: hi Rosita, Did you solved it?

Comment: Yes, I just forgot to paste two axml files..

Comment: Now I have another problem binding second label on xamarin.map.infowindow

Comment: Then please post it as another question

Comment: And also you can provide answer to this question  as well. Maybe it will helpfull for somebody else

Comment: I will do, thank you

Comment: Anand write your comment like a answer, I will accept it !

Comment: haha. No. You resolved it right? The credit should be yours. Please post it what have you done. BTW thanks